# Display a row of the current session

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So in my users table there are 5 columns. Id, username, password, email and money.

The money column is an int which is supposed to show how much money that user has. (I'm making a game).

I'm trying to make a script which displays how much money the user in the current session has, but my script displays the money for every user.

My code:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "database4";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);



if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['money'];
    }
} else {
    echo "You have no items yet!";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

How would I do this?

Comment: you have missing where clause in your select query

Comment: This is just off the cuff, but are you scoping your SQL query to return only the value for the current user? Your `'SELECT * FROM users'` statement makes me believe you need to scope that query a bit more.

Comment: Yes that's what i'm trying to do. But what is the WHERE supposed to do? Is this correct? $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '".$_SESSION['user_name']."'"; haha i dont really have a clue how to do this

Comment: Seth, which variable holds the value of the current user? You need to specifiy something like `'SELECT MONEY FROM USERS WHERE USERS.ID = CURRENT_USER.ID'`. I don't know if you have a variable that is being passed in that accomplishes that.

Comment: The "WHERE" will scope your results so that only the money value for a user with an ID that matches the ID for the one you specified (the current user) will be returned. I can't give you a definitive answer because I don't see where you would pull that value from in your code. You need to match the primary keys! A unique identifier that matches ID to ID - unless username is your primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missing where clause in your select query.

it would be something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='{$_SESSION['user_id']}'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

You just need to replace `$_SESSION['user_id']` with the user id you are storing while user gets logged in.

**EDIT:**

Make sure you have `session_start();` where page starts, additionally you may create unique index on email column in users table.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='{$_SESSION['email']}'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: Notice: Undefined index: user_id in C:\xampp2\htdocs\money.php on line 16 from that :S

Comment: cause `user_id` doesn't exists in `$_SESSION` variable, you have to replace it with actual index.

Comment: Like this?: $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id']; I use this login system https://github.com/panique/php-login-minimal

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp2\htdocs\money.php on line 16

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp2\htdocs\money.php on line 21 :S

Comment: do you have `session_start();` at the top of page ? seems that's missing

Comment: Yeah I do. This is what it looks like: http://i.gyazo.com/6de8189a8537eb8e8af244128f5ad255.png

Comment: ok, try some debugging, put `print_r($_SESSION);` after `session_start();`, and see what result comes

Comment: Oh wait I did a stupid mistake, and put column name in query as email instead of user_email :facepalm:. THANK you for your help :) it works now